# How to know if a string variable (state) is a good predictor of another variable (social_class)

Tags: distributions, predictive-models, predictor

I have a dataset of users, states, and social classes (each user lives in a state and has a certain social class). The dataset consists in only 2 columns: state and social class, and each row corresponds to one user. There are millions of distinct users (rows), 27 distinct states ([1,2,...,27]) and 6 distinct social classes in my dataset (['a','b',...,'f']).

Example of my dataset in a pandas df:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'state':[1,1,2,2], 'sclass':['a','b','a','c']}, dtype='str')
```

Both states and social classes are string variables, although I could map the social classes to numbers since they can be ordered (being "a" the highest number and "f" the lowest), but the states cannot be "ordered".

I would like to know if the `state` (where users live), is a good predictor of the `social class` (that the users have). Is there any parameter to quantify how good is a predictor? I am completely new to these kind of problems, so explanations are very welcome. As I understand, if each state has a more or less uniform distribution of social classes, then the states are not good predictors. On the other hand, if each state has a Dirac delta distribution centered in any of the social classes, then the states are good predcitors for social classes.

The next step would be to check if using very small censal units (around 500k distinct censal units) instead of states, gives better results (i.e. if the censal units are indeed a good predictor of the social class).